# Removing utc info from yfinance dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, yfinance

How can I remove the utc portion of a DF created from a yfinance?  Every example I and approach I seen has failed.
eg:

```
df = yf.download('2022-01-01', '2023-01-06', interval = '60m' )
pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
```

error: 3806  #If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

```
        KeyError: 'Datetime'
```

As well as the following approaches
`enter code here`df = df.reset_index()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Datetime', "Close"])

df.rename(columns = {'Date': 'ds'}, inplace = True)
df.rename(columns = {'Close':'y'}, inplace = True)
#df['ds'] = df['ds'].dt.date
#df['ds'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df['ds'], tz = None)
#df['ds'] = df['ds'].dt.floor("Min")
#df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'].dt.tz_convert(None))
#df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime['ds']
#pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
df['ds'].dt.tz_localize(None)
print(df)
```

with similar errors,   Any help or pointer will greatly appreciated I have spent the entire morning on this.

Thanks in advance
BTT

Comment: please give an example how exactly your time input looks like and how you want to it to look like
the KeyError: 'Datetime' results because you use 
df.rename(columns = {'Date': 'ds'}, inplace = True)
instead of
df.rename(columns = {'Datetime': 'ds'}, inplace = True)

Comment: Did you re-assign back to the df ? E.g. `df["ds"] = df['ds'].dt.tz_localize(None)`

Comment: The original dataframe:

Comment: The original dateframe: datetime                                                                        
2022-10-13 09:30:00-04:00  3520.370117  3550.969971  3491.580078  3530.909912   
2022-10-13 10:30:00-04:00  3530.399902  3635.229980  3528.709961  3612.879883   
2022-10-13 11:30:00-04:00  3613.020020  3662.510010  3609.360107  3624.219971   
2022-10-13 12:30:00-04:00  3624.020020  3667.290039  3622.350098  3663.360107   
2022-10-13 13:30:00-04:00  3663.439941  3675.080078  3650.709961  3651.429932

Comment: What I am looking for is just date time portion without the utc info 2022-10-16 15:30.  The above suggestions and typo fixes still left me with the underlying issue.

Comment: The UTC offset is effectively removed by calling `.dt.localize(None)`. If you want to get a specific *format*, use `strftime` (which will give you a string). If you want to manipulate the datetime itself, e.g. use `.dt.floor("min")` to set the seconds to zero.

Comment: I got got what I was looking for is df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None) I was confused thinking the Datetime was a data column as opposed the index.  Thank You!

Comment: Please edit your question and add requested details there. Do not use comments. (Once added to the question, as formatted text, please delete your comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code interprets `'2022-01-01'` as the first and required argument `tickers`.
This date is not a valid ticker, so `yf.download()` does not return any price and volume data.
Try:

```py
df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', start='2022-01-01', end='2023-01-06', interval = '60m' )
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)
```